# Configure LookUp field using Sharepoint PNP Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I create a column "TitleLookUp" of type *LookUp*, how can I access the column and configure the information via PNP PowerShell?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to configure?

Comment: @Mike2500 Get Information from, In this column

Answer (score 4):

Example, we can configure the lookup list and show field for lookup field using the PowerShell below.

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz –Credentials (Get-Credential) 

$listName="CustomList"
$fieldName="TitleLookUp"
$lookupListTitle="LookupList"

$lookupList=Get-PnPList -Identity $lookupListTitle
$field = Get-PnPField -List $listName -Identity $fieldName 
[xml]$schemaXml=$field.SchemaXml
$schemaXml.OuterXml
$schemaXml.Field.Attributes["List"].Value = "{" + $lookupList.Id + "}"
$schemaXml.Field.Attributes["ShowField"].Value = "Title"
Set-PnPField -List $listName -Identity $fieldName -Values @{SchemaXml=$schemaXml.OuterXml}
```

Comment: How can I add this column to another site? I already have the column on `site A` and I want to add on `site B`.

Comment: If you want to add lookup field to new site, we can use Add-PnPFieldFromXml to achieve it.

Comment: I tried but is not receiving the values from the list, as you can see here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255795/insert-lookup-column-in-list-using-sharepoint-pnp-powershell

Comment: You need add lookup list in another site, and then add lookup field to list in this site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation for Set-PNPListItem with examples of set LookUp or MultiLookUp values: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: The site that you provided is for insert data in column and not to configure it.

Comment: Sorry bad reading from my side :D Here:
$list = "listname"
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$lkField = Add-PnPField -List $list -DisplayName "fieldname" -InternalName "fieldname" -Type Lookup -AddToDefaultView
$lkField = $lookupField.TypedObject
$lkField.LookupList = "Lookup List ID"
$lkField.LookupField = "Lookup List field name"
$lkField.update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to create a new lookup field via pnp powershell? While add-pnpfield supports adding basic fields, it does not support lookups (yet). See add-pnpfieldfromxml, which allows us to specify an xml schema. It's more work, but it supports the more advanced options. For an example of how to do this for a lookup field, see this [answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8553998c-de38-4b7f-b909-f871a4345520/add-lookup-column-using-pnp-powershell?forum=SP2016).

Comment: What's the difference between _List, ID and SourceID_?