# Insert LookUp column in list using Sharepoint PNP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, lookup-column, pnp-powershell

I've this code bellow

*OfertaParticulares*

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Negocio/OfertaParticulares -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$listName="Páginas"
$fieldName="LookUp"
$lookupListTitle="Páginas"
$lookupList=Get-PnPList -Identity $lookupListTitle
$field = Get-PnpField -List $listName -Identity $fieldName
[xml]$schemaXml=$field.SchemaXml
$schemaXml.OuterXml
$schemaXml.Field.Attributes["List"].Value = "{" + $lookupList.Id + "}"
$schemaXml.Field.Attributes["ShowField"].Value = "Title"
Set-PnPField -List $listName -Identity $fieldName -Values @{SchemaXml=$schemaXml.OuterXml}
```

And the result is:

```
<Field Type="LookupMulti" 
DisplayName="TítuloDetalhe" 
Required="FALSE" 
EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" 
List="{d97620a4-959b-44d8-9111-a9eeb8158382}"
ShowField="Title" 
Mult="TRUE" 
Sortable="FALSE" 
UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE" 
RelationshipDeleteBehavior="None" 
ID="{db74d50c-df97-47e8-812a-f1bbd31327cd}" 
SourceID="{d97620a4-959b-44d8-9111-a9eeb8158382}" 
StaticName="T_x00ed_tuloDetalhe" 
Name="T_x00ed_tuloDetalhe" 
ColName="int15" 
RowOrdinal="0"
Version="5" 
Group="" />
```

I'm trying to insert the result in *ComunicacoesDeNegocio* like this:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Normativo/ComunicacoesDeNegocio -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$xml = '<Field Type="LookupMulti" 
DisplayName="TítuloDetalhe" 
Required="FALSE" 
EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" 
List="{d97620a4-959b-44d8-9111-a9eeb8158382}" 
ShowField="Title" 
Mult="TRUE" 
Sortable="FALSE" 
UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE" 
RelationshipDeleteBehavior="None" 
ID="{db74d50c-df97-47e8-812a-f1bbd31327cd}" 
SourceID="{d97620a4-959b-44d8-9111-a9eeb8158382}" 
StaticName="T_x00ed_tuloDetalhe" 
Name="T_x00ed_tuloDetalhe" ColName="int15" 
RowOrdinal="0" 
Version="5" Group="" />'
Add-PnPFieldFromXml -List "Páginas" -FieldXml $xml
```

When I see the property of the column "Get information from" (Obter informações de) is empty as you can see:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is cause you are creating cross-site reference and it is NOT supported.

https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/**Negocio**/OfertaParticulares https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/**Normativo**/ComunicacoesDeNegocio

You must have lists in the same Web for using of LookUp Columns.

Comment: There is another way to solve this problem? I can't have the lists in the same Web.

Comment: There are some third-parts applications which can be used for Cross-Site LookUp Columns, try google it. Tomorrow i can look for you too.
If this is correct, make this as answer please :)